# Retrieve uncommitted entity from DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

How do I retrieve uncommitted entities from a DbContext?

Consider the following test:

```
    [Test]
    public void AddAndRetrieveUncommittedTenant()
    {
        _tenantRepository.Create("testtenant");
        var tenant = _tenantRepository.GetTenantByName("testtenant");

        Assert.AreEqual("testtenant", tenant.Name);
    }
```

The test fails because `tenant` is `null`.

There is a lot of specific business code in between, but it boils down to:

In my `Repository` class the method `GetTenantByName` in the end calls the `GetAll` method.

```
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.AsQueryable();
    }

    private IDbSet<TEntity> DbSet
    {
        get { return Context.Set<TEntity>(); }
    }
```

and on a class that extends the `DbContext` I have the following method:

```
    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint on `return base.Set<TEntity>();` I can see that the entity is available in the repository (via the `local` property).

---

[image]

---

How can I retrieve the uncommitted entity from my repository?

Comment: What is an "uncommitted entity"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a class that I derive from `DbContext` and add the following method to access what entities have changed.  This should also tell you how to access the changed entities in your `DbContext` as well:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> ChangedEntities
{
    get { return base.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged); }
}
```

`ChangeTracker` is a public property on `DbContext`, so you can also access this property from an external class as well:

```
var dirtyEntities = myDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
```

Or, you can get more specific, if you want to find entities that have been added/modified, etc:

```
var addedEntities = myDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added);
var modifiedEntities = myDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);
```

And so on.

Comment: Hey Brian, this is probably it. I am trying to get from `IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry>` to `IEnumerable<TEntity>` which seems harder than I expected. A `DbEntityEntry` is some kind of invisible wrapper around my entity and I can't seem to get it out (well, not so that the compiler agrees, runtime I can even see the properties of my entity)

Comment: @bas, yes, EF wraps your entity in some kind of dynamic proxy that isn't necessarily assignable to the original entity type (that I've found).  What exactly do you want to accomplish?  The `DbContext` will still have the actual entity (in its changed state), so can you use the `ChangeTracker` to get the Id of the entity that has been modified, then retrieve the actual entity from the `DbContext`?

Comment: The first step is done now, I can use your suggested approach to retrieve the entities in added state. The problem is that my current interface is `IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()`, which I use to `Include` navigation properties. If I change my code to `IEnumerable<TEntity>` I get stuck in the rest of my business code. But, the good news is, your part seems to work so I'll accept the answer and start puzzling :). Thx Brian!

Answer (score 2):

Just do as simple transaction below:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                        new TransactionOptions()
                        {
                            IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
                        }))
{
    var employees = _context.Employees.ToList();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

If you wanna fetch the data synchronously add TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled to above code:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                        new TransactionOptions()
                        {
                            IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
                        },
                        TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    var employees = await _context.Employees.ToListAsync();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, you can have your own extension method for the above transaction:

```
public static async Task<List<T>> ToListWithNoLockAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    List<T> result = default;
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                            new TransactionOptions()
                            {
                                IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
                            },
                            TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        result = await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
        scope.Complete();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and use it as simple as below:

```
var employees = dbContext.Employees
                          .AsNoTracking()
                          .Where(a => a.IsDelete == false)
                          .ToListWithNoLockAsync();
```

Comment: I don't think the question was about reading uncommitted data from the database.